# How to convert an Eigen sparse matrix into an array in C++ using the?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have created a sparse matrix `mat` in C++ using the Eigen package. The matrix works fine, but I am trying to convert it into an array to use as a bitmap. The size of `mat` is N+1.

Naively, I tried doing the following:

```
  double zmat[N+1][N+1];

  for(int i=0; i<=N; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<=N; j++){
          zmat[i][j]=mat.coeffRef(i,j);
          }
  }
```

But this is gives me an exception when I debug:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0116B2C7 in Open_GL_test.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x001D2000).
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the value of `N`? It must be large, you hit a stack overflow.

Comment: why do you use this `N+1` notation? IMHO `zmat[N][N]` and `i<N`/`j<N` is much cleaner

Comment: @CoryKramer N = 600 in this example.

Comment: @tobi303 This matrix is being used to set up a 1-D finite element problem.  I am letting N denote the number of segments, so there are N+1 points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double zmat[N+1][N+1];
```

This is what is causing you trouble. Declaring a large matrix as a local variable in a function is not a good idea. Local variables are allocated on the stack. Many machines limit the size of the stack to a smallish amount of data. On my machine, the stack limit is about 8 megabytes. That means a value of `N` larger than about a thousand will immediately result in stack overflow. A value of `N` larger than several hundred (but smaller than a thousand) will result in a hard-to-trace stack overflow somewhere further down the call tree.

Don't allocate large amounts of data on the stack. Some alternatives are to

- Declare the variable at namespace scope,
- Allocate (and later free) the matrix using `new` and `delete`,
- Use an ordinary Eigen matrix, which does the `new` and `delete` for you.

Answer (score 1):

[David Hammen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31184135/2899559) answer is the correct one (`double zmat[N+1][N+1];` is too large for the stack). However, I feel the need to throw in my two cents regarding your usage.

The double loop is unnecessarily verbose and slow. Even worse, using `coeffref` on each element of the matrix is actually making the matrix effectively dense. In the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#a4386da578a119f7b500d0b22cab2de0e) for `coeffRef` it says:

> If the element does not exist then it is inserted via the insert(Index,Index) function which itself turns the matrix into a non compressed form if that was not the case.
>   This is a O(log(nnz_j)) operation (binary search) plus the cost of insert(Index,Index) function if the element does not already exist.

This means that not only is it verbose, it's going to add to your memory requirements and may become a bottleneck. You can instead use

```
MatrixXd::Map(&zmat[0], (N+1), (N+1)) = mat.toDense();
```

or

```
MatrixXd::Map(zmat, (N+1), (N+1)) = mat.toDense();  // double zmat = new ...
```

This is not only more readable, but much more efficient as well.

Comment: This won't work. The double loop is needed because `mat.coeffRef(i,j)`  is a sparse matrix.

Comment: Oops, missed that. Fixed.